# I need to make unversal method in my Provider Classes

Tags: python

It's my view:

```
class TakeToken(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            provider = GitProvider(request.data['provider'])
        except KeyError:
            return Response('Not found', status=status.HTTP_404)
```

I need to make a universal method so that the provider class is derived from request.data['provider']. For example, there is git in request.data['provider'], I need to create an instance of the Getprovider class, how do I do this?

It's base provider:

```
class AuthProvider(ABC):
    """contains all methods to work with social providers"""

    @abstractmethod
    def get_data(self, token):
        pass
```

It's git provider:

```
class GitProvider(AuthProvider):
    def get_data(self, token):
        rq = requests.get(url=self.provider['oauth_url'])
                         
        if rq.status_code == 200:
            self.data = rq.json()
            self.token = token
        else:
            raise KeyError('token is not valid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say using factory pattern. This pattern involves a factory method that takes the provider name as an input and returns an instance of the corresponding provider class.

In your case, you need a way to map the strings like "git" to their respective provider classes like `GitProvider`. You can achieve this by maintaining a dictionary that maps these strings to the classes. How you can do this:

1. Create a factory method:

```py
class ProviderFactory:
    providers = {
        'git': GitProvider,
        # Add other providers here
    }

    @staticmethod
    def get_provider(provider_name):
        provider_class = ProviderFactory.providers.get(provider_name.lower())
        if provider_class:
            return provider_class()
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Provider '{provider_name}' not supported")
```

2. Integrate factory in your view:

```py
class TakeToken(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            provider_name = request.data['provider']
            provider = ProviderFactory.get_provider(provider_name)
        except KeyError:
            return Response('Provider name is missing', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except ValueError as e:
            return Response(str(e), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # Continue with your logic using the provider instance
```

3. Implement provider classes:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AuthProvider(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_data(self, token):
        pass

class GitProvider(AuthProvider):
    def get_data(self, token):
        # Implementation for GitProvider
        pass
```

This approach allows you to easily extend your application with more providers by just adding them to the `ProviderFactory.providers`. It keeps the provider creation logic centralized and makes your `TakeToken` view cleaner and more maintainable.